# Increment a column value in Oracle

Tags: oracle, counter

I need to increment a column value based on certain criteria.

I have 2 tables -

Table A has ID, Name, Date, and so on

```
Id  Name    Date
1   ABC 3/1/2014
2   ABC 4/1/2014
3   ABC 5/1/2014
4   DEF 4/1/2014
5   DEF 5/1/2014
6   HIJ 1/1/2014
7   HIJ 2/1/2014
8   HIJ 3/1/2014
9   HIJ 4/1/2014
10  HIJ 5/1/2014
```

Table B has Name(foreign Key), Date(will be same as Table A), counter, and so on.

```
Name    Date    Counter(the value that I need is in this column, it will be zero by default)
ABC 3/1/2014    0
ABC 4/1/2014    1
ABC 5/1/2014    2
DEF 4/1/2014    0
DEF 5/1/2014    1
HIJ 1/1/2014    0
HIJ 2/1/2014    1
HIJ 3/1/2014    2
HIJ 4/1/2014    3
HIJ 5/1/2014    4
```

I need to increment the counter as above shown in the table. So for each name the counter should reset and start from 0 and the dates for each names will be different, so I need to take that into account(meaning I cannot assume 1/31/2014 to be 0 for all the names. The counter would end at say 5/1/2014. So I need to update the counter till the date has reached 5/1/2014.

What is the best way to accomplish this? I am trying to write a procedure, but not sure how I can update the counter for different names in the cursors. I am open to any suggestion. Thanks.

**EDIT::: Updated Code**

```
Update Table B, set counter = 0;

declare

cursor rec is

select a.name, a.postingdate, b.counter
from table A a
inner join table B b
on a.name = b.name
order by a.name, a.date;

begin

    open rec;
    LOOP
        fetch rec into v_name, v_date, v_counter;
        exit...........

**<How can I reset my counter here for different names>**
        if date < to_date ('01-may-2014', 'dd-mon-yy') then v_counter := v_counter +1;  
        end if;

        update table b set counter = v_counter where current of rec;
    END LOOP;
    commit;
END;
```

Comment: Show some code. Even if it's buggy or ugly or whatever. You have to show some code, otherwise it seems like you are asking for someone else to do your job.

Comment: Fair enough. I have updated the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please copy/paste to see results:

```
SELECT deptno, ename (your_counter-1) new_counter FROM 
 ( SELECT deptno, ename
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY deptno, ename) your_counter
FROM scott.emp
);

10  CLARK   0
10  KING    1
10  MILLER  2
20  ADAMS   0
20  FORD    1
20  JONES   2
20  SCOTT   3
....
```

In your case you partition by Name.

Comment: Thanks, I used this to update my query and I scrapped my procedure.

Answer (score 3):

The following query should do what you want:

```
SELECT NAME, TO_CHAR(SOME_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), ROWCOUNT-1 AS COUNTER
  FROM (SELECT NAME,
               SOME_DATE,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME
                                  ORDER BY ID, NAME, SOME_DATE) ROWCOUNT
          FROM TABLE_A);
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0738f2/5)

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks Bob. I used Art's query and got what I wanted. Thanks for your time.